# How to make php file to be secret

Tags: php, security, hosting

in one of my php file on my wordpress website I have private code that perform authorisation checking. So I want to be sure nobody (except me of course) can see that code, only can run it.

How to do that?

Actually I am quite new in php, wordpress, hosting etc. So I don't know how it works. Maybe my code is secured by default. I even tried to download my php file as unlogged user and I didn't find the way how to do that. I tried just type in browser something like:
www.mywebsite.com/myfile.php

But it run the php by default which is great. But I need to be sure the php file will never be downloaded by unauthorized user.

Comment: if you access a php file through a web server with PHP support (which you are since you're running WP on it as well), the server will parse the PHP code before it sends the response to the client. The only thing that will be returned is any output of your code, not the code itself. However, anyone can still execute the code inside that file by calling the file directly, like you've done: www.site.com/thefile.php. If you want to prevent that and only allow you to execute it, you need to add some type of authentication. Either create your own or use basic auth or similar.

Comment: Great thanks Magnus, but the question is how to do that. Of course I tried to google it, but there are thousends of threads for that, and for such new noob like me it is difficult to decide which solution is for my case.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: well we don't know the specifics of your case so we can't really advise you on that either.

Comment: Hmm... My case is to be sure nobody can see the code of my php file

Comment: Well as already explained, you don't need authentication for that. In fact you should not need to do anything at all to achieve that aim. Authentication is if you want to stop people from running some of your code, not to stop them from _viewing_ the code.

Comment: And if you _do_ need to stop people from _running_ the code, then like you said there are many possible ways to implement authentication and what's best for you would likely depend on a much wider context than just that basic requirement.

Comment: Great. That’s perfect news. Running code durectly is not a problem. Just want to prevent by watching code or debuging. But if it is prevent by default, that’s great. Thanks

Comment: Yes that's correct. Magnus Eriksson's comment explains already why that's the case

Comment: just to pile on, the answers so far are correct. i just want to make sure you understand that if someone gets your PHP code, they can read it, so I hope you have no secrets in there like passwords or encryption keys in the code!

Comment: Oh..!! Michael!! Everything was great until you told that „so I hope you have no secrets in there...”. Of course I have planty of secret data in my php code, that’s why I want to prevent somebody to see the code. But if somebody run the code there is no problem, the problem I would have if somebody see code. So how is that?

Comment: If someone hacks your server or there is some other unforeseen bug which leaks code then that could happen.